# Drupal Hidden Nodes, CSS and VBO

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, hidden

I got a problem with the drupal module "hidden nodes".
I created a view to hide or unhide a couple of nodes at the same time (with Views Bulk Operations). But it's not working. When I hide some nodes with VBO the View says that the nodes are hidden afterwards, but they are not.
Even so i noticed that the CSS-Class "node-is-hidden", which is added to the menu link after saving a node in hidden mode, is not removed after unhiding nodes with VBO.
The other way round i got the same problem. After hiding nodes with VBO the CSS-Class is not added to the menu-links.

Someone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have Views query or result caching enabled. Disable it under the Advanced fieldset on the settings page for your view.